# Rails ActiveRecord Where With AND OR Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In Rails I'm trying to write a complex query like this

```
where("A OR (B AND C) OR (D AND E AND F) OR (G AND H AND I))"
```

However struggling to make it work using just ActiveRecord without SQL. The following scope using SQL produces the correct results.

```
scope :for_teacher_sql, ->(teacher) { 
  where("(announcements.user_id = :user_id) OR " +
        "(announcements.school_id IS NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL) OR " +
        "(announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL AND school_teachers.teacher_id = :user_id) OR " + 
        "(announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NOT NULL AND classroom_teachers.teacher_id = :user_id)", user_id: teacher.id ).
  left_outer_joins(school: :school_teachers).left_outer_joins(classroom: :classroom_teachers) if teacher.present? }
```

And the generated SQL looks correct.

```
SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "schools" ON "schools"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "schools"."id" = "announcements"."school_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "school_teachers" ON "school_teachers"."school_id" = "schools"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "classrooms" ON "classrooms"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "classrooms"."id" = "announcements"."classroom_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "classroom_teachers" ON "classroom_teachers"."classroom_id" = "classrooms"."id" 
WHERE "announcements"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (
  (announcements.user_id = '80e699e6-77f2-4e13-8cef-02c9d8ee2ac0') OR 
  (announcements.school_id IS NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL) OR 
  (announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL AND school_teachers.teacher_id = '80e699e6-77f2-4e13-8cef-02c9d8ee2ac0') OR 
  (announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NOT NULL AND classroom_teachers.teacher_id = '80e699e6-77f2-4e13-8cef-02c9d8ee2ac0'))
```

Doing a hybrid ActiveRecord with SQL seems to produce the correct results as well.

```
scope :for_teacher_hybrid, ->(teacher) { 
  where("announcements.user_id = ?", teacher.id).or(
  where("announcements.school_id IS NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL")).or(
  where("announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL AND school_teachers.teacher_id = ?", teacher.id)).or(
  where("announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NOT NULL AND classroom_teachers.teacher_id = ?", teacher.id)).
  left_outer_joins(school: :school_teachers).left_outer_joins(classroom: :classroom_teachers) if teacher.present? }
```

Although the generated SQL has some additional brackets.

```
SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "schools" ON "schools"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "schools"."id" = "announcements"."school_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "school_teachers" ON "school_teachers"."school_id" = "schools"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "classrooms" ON "classrooms"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "classrooms"."id" = "announcements"."classroom_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "classroom_teachers" ON "classroom_teachers"."classroom_id" = "classrooms"."id" WHERE "announcements"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (
  (
    (
      (announcements.user_id = '80e699e6-77f2-4e13-8cef-02c9d8ee2ac0') OR 
      (announcements.school_id IS NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL)
    ) OR 
    (announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NULL AND school_teachers.teacher_id = '80e699e6-77f2-4e13-8cef-02c9d8ee2ac0')
  ) OR 
  (announcements.school_id IS NOT NULL AND announcements.classroom_id IS NOT NULL AND classroom_teachers.teacher_id = '80e699e6-77f2-4e13-8cef-02c9d8ee2ac0')
)
```

However I can't get it to work just using ActiveRecord without SQL.

```
scope :for_teacher_plain, ->(teacher) { 
  where(user_id: teacher.id).or(
  where.not(school: nil).where.not(classroom: nil)).or(
  where.not(school: nil).where(classroom: nil).where(school: { school_teachers: { teacher_id: teacher.id } })).or(
  where.not(school: nil).where.not(classroom: nil).where(classroom: { classroom_teachers: { teacher_id: teacher.id } })).
  left_outer_joins(school: :school_teachers).left_outer_joins(classroom: :classroom_teachers) if teacher.present? && teacher.teacher? }
```

The AND queries are not grouped inside the OR conditions, so I must not be writing them correctly.

```
SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "schools" ON "schools"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "schools"."id" = "announcements"."school_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "school_teachers" ON "school_teachers"."school_id" = "schools"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "classrooms" ON "classrooms"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "classrooms"."id" = "announcements"."classroom_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "classroom_teachers" ON "classroom_teachers"."classroom_id" = "classrooms"."id" 
WHERE "announcements"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (
  (
    ("announcements"."user_id" = $1 OR "announcements"."school_id" IS NOT NULL AND "announcements"."classroom_id" IS NOT NULL) 
    OR "announcements"."school_id" IS NOT NULL AND "announcements"."classroom_id" IS NULL AND "school_teachers"."teacher_id" = $2
  ) 
    OR "announcements"."school_id" IS NOT NULL AND "announcements"."classroom_id" IS NOT NULL AND "classroom_teachers"."teacher_id" = $3
)
```

Note, I'm using [paranoia](https://rubygems.org/gems/paranoia) which is why the *deleted_at IS NULL* statements are being included.

I can fallback to using the SQL version but I'd really like to understand why the pure ActiveRecord isn't working, and how to write complex AND with OR conditions like this.